# TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.fromEvent is not a function in ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal module

Tags: angular

## When I try to navigate to any componenet which using ng2-bs3-modal I am getting below error. Same code working in different application.#

The error I am getting.

core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.fromEvent is not a function
TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.fromEvent is not a function
    at ModalInstance.push../node_modules/ng2-bs3-modal/components/modal-instance.js.ModalInstance.init (modal-instance.js:52)
    at new ModalInstance (modal-instance.js:12)
    at new ModalComponent (modal.js:17)
    at createClass (core.js:9294)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:9179)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:10399)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10715)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10634)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:10427)
    at createRootView (core.js:10313)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3811)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)

### Dependencies##

```
dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~6.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~6.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "~6.1.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~6.1.9",
    "@angular/http": "~6.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~6.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~6.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "~6.1.9",
    "@ngui/datetime-picker": "^0.16.2",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.6.1",
    "clipboard": "~1.7.1",
    "core-js": "~2.4.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "~3.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.1",
    "systemjs": "~0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~6.0.3",
    "@ngui/utils": "~0.7.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.46",
    "canonical-path": "~0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "~2.4.0",
    "lodash": "~4.17.11",
    "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.10.4",
    "protractor": "~5.4.1",
    "rimraf": "~2.5.4",
    "tslint": "~3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Sample code in my componenet.

`````
import { ModalComponent } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';
import { NguiDatetimePickerModule } from '@ngui/datetime-picker';
import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination';
import { IETLTaskSetup } from '../../../Models/etltasksetup';
import { DBOperation } from '../../../Shared/enum';
import { Environment } from '../../../Shared/enum';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Global } from '../../../Shared/global';
import { ISecurity } from '../../../Models/security';

@Component({
    templateUrl: `../View/etltasksetup.component.html`
})

export class ETLTaskComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('modal') modal: ModalComponent;
    @ViewChild('modal2') modal2: ModalComponent;````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Updated ng2-bs3-modal to latest that is 0.15.0. Then I updated all the codes related to ng2-bs3-modal like below
old code

```
<modal #modal2>
    <form >
        <modal-header [showDismiss]="true">

        </modal-header>
        <modal-body>

        </modal-body>
        <modal-footer style="background-color:cornsilk;">

        </modal-footer>
    </form>
<modal>
```

new code

```
<bs-modal #modal2>
    <form >
        <bs-modal-header [showDismiss]="true">

        </bs-modal-header>
        <bs-modal-body>

        </bs-modal-body>
        <bs-modal-footer style="background-color:cornsilk;">

        </bs-modal-footer>
    </form>
</bs-modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't import `onInit`

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
```

Edit:

In `Rxjs 6.x .fromEvent()` is not supported anymore. You have to show us where you're using it in your code. If it's happening in your NodeModule `ModalInstance` and you don't control the code, you need to get rid of that old module or update it.

Example on how to use it

```
// RxJS v6+
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

//create observable that emits click events
const source = fromEvent(document, 'click');
//map to string with given event timestamp
const example = source.pipe(map(event => `Event time: ${event.timeStamp}`));
//output (example): 'Event time: 7276.390000000001'
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: it is there on the top, it missed when I pasted here

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am getting error from this ng2-bs3-modal  node module.  In browser developer tool I can see the codes
"use strict";
var Observable_1 = require('rxjs/Observable');
require('rxjs/add/operator/map');
require('rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent');

this line throwing error.
  this.shown = Observable_1.Observable.fromEvent(this.$modal, this.shownEventName).

I am using latest version of   "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.15.0",just updated. still not working.

Comment: It won't work at all in that version of rxjs. You have the following options. 1. Downgrade rxjs, remove the node module, or update the node module manually. If you update manually every time you upgrade the module your code is overwritten and you have to update it again. Try to post contribute on their GIT with a pull request on the fix, or post it on their git for them to update the modal. Either way it won't be usable with the current version of rxjs.

Comment: I updated the module to latest version, it worked. But I have to do a lot of code changes